# Install Psychopy packages to Python to run from Emacs - Wx package won't install

Tags: python, emacs, psychopy

I'd like to install Psychopy to my main Python install in order to be able to code and test the code in Emacs.

However - every time I try to install Psychopy and run a Psychopy scripts from my main Python install I receive an error saying I don't have the Wx module. I've been unable to install the Wx module for reasons I can't quite figure out.

Has anyone had this issue and figured out a way around it?

Comment: I think wx is only required for opening gui dialogs, not for displaying the main stimulus window. Try removing any `import gui` statement as a work-around for scripts that don't need to show a dialog box.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using anaconda (as stated in response to Gagandeep) then there is a wxpython package in the anaconda distribution:

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/wxpython

Did you install that or did you try to install wxpython from its website? If you installed the anaconda wxpython and it didn't install correctly then this is an issue to take up with the people that packaged it.

Either way, this title is misleading: this issue is not about PsychoPy and emacs, but about installing wxpython on anaconda

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the clarification about root issue.